# Attributes.Remove does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
ddlFromCurrency.Attributes.Remove("class");
```

I want to remove `class="xx"` from html element with Attributes.Remove but not wokrking. `Attributes.Add` works but `Attributes.Remove` doesn't. Any idea why?

Comment: Where in your code are you trying this? page load? pre render? somewhere else?

Comment: i make this in page_load() yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `ddlFromCurrency` is a `DropDownList` you can just do

```
ddlFromCurrency.CssClass = string.Empty;
```

For a `DropDownList` your code won't work since on page load `ddlFromCurrency` doesn't have an attribute `class`

Answer (score 5):

The attributes collection is for optionally adding extra html attributes that are not part of the control already. The "class" attribute in this case is generated via the CssClass property and rendered.

You simply need to set CssClass to string.empty and it will not render.

```
ddlFromCurrency.CssClass = string.Emtpy;
```